# Javascript / CSS masonry - Respect columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to use Masonry style (CSS or Javascript) to define a specific grid.

I made an example of what I expect : https://jsfiddle.net/7s2e41tL/

I have a column-based grid, and I use static position and margins and width, it's good but every div is positioned after the previous one :

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 |   |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 2 |   |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 3 | 3 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   |   |   | 4 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

And this is what I want :

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| 1 | 2 |   | 4 | 4 |
+---+---+---+---+---+
|   | 3 | 3 |   |   |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

I tried Masonry script, and according to the doc, this example seems good :

```
$grid.isotope({ 
    layoutMode: 'cellsByColumn' 
})
```

But it doesn't respect columns. Is there a way to "Mason" my layout according to columns ?

I tried flex CSS, different plugins, and I am trying to build something simple with a matrice based system, but I can't find a way..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS property `display: grid`.

I took your example here:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.grid-container {
  background: lightgrey;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 500px; /* You need this only if you want your columns to have a specific width. Here 5*100px = 500px */
  height: 200px; /* Same for the height */
  grid-gap: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.grid-container div{
  background: red;
}

.el-1{
  grid-column: 1/2;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.el-2{
  grid-column: 2/3;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}

.el-3{
  grid-column: 2/4;
  grid-row: 2/3;
}

.el-4{
  grid-column: 4/6;
  grid-row: 1/2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="el-1">1</div>
  <div class="el-2">2</div>
  <div class="el-3">3</div>
  <div class="el-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah thanks for the idea, but as you imagine, I want something I can automate. I will have many different cases. But I guess I will have to develop something from my own using this

Comment: Then, based on your example there’s no way to guess how you’d like it to behave. So let’s say you take some images, or content and then what? Should their width fit into one column, two columns sometimes but when? What about the height? There are many many possibilities...

Comment: Yes, but not that many, if you use a kind of Matrice (x and y), you just need to check if {x,y} is taken, if so you try {x+1,y} and so on ...

Comment: Yes I see, so the images would always be a multiple of 100px? Either way, you can’t really do that kind of conditional check with CSS you would need JavaScript. Or another strategy.